# Deleting Gmail messages in Ruby's Imap module

Tags: ruby, gmail, imap

thanks for clicking here to possibly help me, or yourself if you're in search of an answer and it's been found.

I've been trying to figure out how to delete messages that have a specific subject from my gmail inbox using Ruby's IMAP module for the past weeks or two, and I cannot get any advice or any other code to work. This is my current script:

```
require 'net/imap'
imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.googlemail.com", 993, true)
imap.login('*censored*', '*censored*')
imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.search(["SUBJECT", "testkeyword"]).each do |message_id|
  imap.copy(message_id, "Trash")
  imap.store(message_id, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted])
end
imap.close
imap.logout
imap.disconnect
```

Comment: The correct mailbox name depends on the gmail user. It's never just 'Trash'. It'll be something like '[Gmail]/Trash'. Apart from that the code looks good.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Change the name of Trash to [Gmail]/Trash

So as it turns out, I can answer my own question thanks to arnt ( a commenter on the original question). All I had to do was change the name of Trash to [Gmail]/Trash.

Comment: You can also determine the name like this:     trash = @imap.list("", "*").find { |m| m.attr.include?(:Trash) } 

Some gmails use [Google Mail] not gmail so you will run into issues unless you detect the correct name